# Inheritance with Member Function Pointers and Templates

Tags: c++

I have two classes:

```
class A {
   public:
      bool funA();
};
class B : public A {
   pubic:
      bool funB();
};
```

and a templated function that takes a function pointer and then calls it against a list of B's:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> getFunc(T (B::func*)()) {
 ....iterator through list of B's calling func....
}
```

If I try to call `getFunc(B::funA)` I get a compile error that "no getFunc(A::funA) exists..."

I can solve the problem by simply creating a second `getFunc` that takes `A::func*` instead of B::, but now I have two functions doing the exact same thing.  Is there a way for me to only end up with one implementation of `getFunc`?

EDIT: I need a pre C++11 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply deduce the entire parameter and extract its return type:

```c++
template<class F,class R=std::result_of_t<F(B&)>>
std::vector<R> getFunc(F&&){return{};}
```

`std::result_of_t` is C++14, for a C++11 compatible solution, use `typename std::result_of<F(B&)>::type`.

For a C++03 solution, simply deduce the class type:

```c++
template <typename T, typename C>
std::vector<T> getFunc(T (C::*func)());
```

Comment: What header is result_of_t in?  #include <type_traits> gets me no such file.

Comment: @mjr Enable C++11 (`-std=c++11`).

Comment: Sorry, got distracted by other problems.  We do not appear to support the new standards.  Is there a solution that is compatible with C++03?  Your solution would work 6 months from now when we do our OS upgrade, but that doesn't help me today.

Comment: That is incredibly simple.  Thanks for putting up with my outdated baseline.

Answer (score 0):

`&B::funA` has type `bool (A::*)()`, not `bool (B::*)()`. You will need to perform a `static_cast`: `static_cast<bool (B::*)()>(&B::funA)`.

Comment: That gets me "invalid static cast from type 'bool (A::*)()' to 'bool (B::*)()'"